# Finding an href link using Python, Selenium, and XPath

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I want to get the *href* from a *<p>* tag using an XPath expression.

I want to use the **text** from *<h1>* tag ('Cable Stripe Knit L/S Polo') and simultaneously **text** from the *<p>* tag ('White') to find the href in the *<p>* tag.

Note: There are more colors of one item (more articles with different *<p>* tags, but the same *<h1>* tag)!

#### HTML source

```
<article>
    <div class="inner-article">
        <a href="/shop/tops-sweaters/ix4leuczr/a1ykz7f2b" style="height:150px;">
        </a>
        <h1>
            <a href="/shop/tops-sweaters/ix4leuczr/a1ykz7f2b" class="name-link">Cable Stripe Knit L/S Polo
            </a>
        </h1>
        <p>
            <a href="/shop/tops-sweaters/ix4leuczr/a1ykz7f2b" class="name-link">White</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</article>
```

I've tried this code, but it didn't work.

```
specificProductColor = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='inner-article' and contains(text(), 'White') and contains(text(), 'Cable')]/p")

driver.get(specificProductColor.get_attribute("href"))
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the HTML source, the XPath expression to get the *href* tags would be something like this:

```
specificProductColors = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='inner-article']//a[contains(text(), 'White') or contains(text(), 'Cable')]")

specificProductColors[0].get_attribute("href")

specificProductColors[1].get_attribute("href")
```

Since there are two hyperlink tags, you should be using *find_elements_by_xpath* which returns a list of elements. In this case it would return two hyperlink tags, and you could get their *href* using the *get_attribute* method.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for reply. Actually, what i'm trying to do is filter one product and choose specific color. There are multiple same products with different colors. (http://imgur.com/ei7o6rS) I tried your code, it worked but both links chose wrong color. I need the code to be as simple as possible and as fast as possible. – Luke LubiX Long 6 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

I've got working code. It's not the fastest one - this part takes approximately 550 ms, but it works. If someone could simplify that, I'd be very thankful :)

It takes all products with the specified keyword (Cable) from the product page and all products with a specified color (White) from the product page as well. It compares *href* links and matches wanted product with wanted color.

I also want to simplify the loop - stop both *for* loops if the links match.

```
specificProduct = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='inner-article']//*[contains(text(), '" + productKeyword[arrayCount] + "')]")
specificProductColor = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='inner-article']//*[contains(text(), '" + desiredColor[arrayCount] + "')]")

for i in specificProductColor:
    specProductColor = i.get_attribute("href")
    for i in specificProduct:
        specProduct = i.get_attribute("href")
        if specProductColor == specProduct:
            print(specProduct)
            wantedProduct = specProduct

driver.get(wantedProduct)
```